# Django. Runserver and migrations

Tags: django

Приступил к изучению Django по разным учебникам. Создал первый проект с админкой[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Начал изучать из второго источника(metanit): добавил новое приложение, написал функцию hello worl,  и добавил path()

И при запуске сервера вылезает : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На сколько я понял, нужно было создавать виртуальную среду для каждого проекта, и сейчас Джаного просит из первого проекта выполнить миграции во второй. Как это исправить?

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Все!!! Вопрос решен. Я неправильно написал path  в urls.py